# Using JFileChooser to load Media files

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to use a `JFileChooser` to load files to play in a MediaPlayer. I'm thinking I have to get the `URI` as a string to achieve this, however, I get errors on illegal characters where there are spaces in the uri. I tried to prevent this by replacing spaces with `%20`, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there any way to get around this or should I use a completely different maneuver to load sound files?

My method looks as follows:

```
private void openFile()
    {
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String uri = selectedFile.getPath();
            String fileToAdd = uri.replace(" ", "%20");
            tracklist.addTrack(fileToAdd);
        }                
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to, but couldn't you simple use `selectedFile.toURI()` (and then use `toString`)?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I'm a complete beginner, so I'll gladly take advice if you think there is a better way to get around it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer consider making it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [`File#toURI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI%28%29) which will give you a [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), which could then use `toString` to generate a `String` representation of the `URI` which could then be added to the list...